# How to get the amount of factors in a number

Tags: python

I have code so far which gets me the factors of a number, however I need the amount of factors in any number inputted. How can I do that?

```
def factor(n):
  factor_values = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
      if n % i == 0:
        factor_values.append(i) 
  values = ""
  for v in factor_values:
    values += str(v) + " "
  return values
```

Comment: Do you not see that, in your code, `factor_values` is a list containing all of the factors?  Do you know how to find the length of a list?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find how many factors does a value have using python, I think because your code using list to save all the factors, you can count all the item using `print(factor_values.len())` which will return the length of a list.

Comment: This is incorrect syntax of method `len()`. If you want to get length of list `factor_values` then you must write `len(factor_values)`

Comment: @rockzxm ah yes, kind of that. I thought it was ```listname.len().``` Thanks a lot for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Does it solve your problem?

```
def factor(n):
    factor_values = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factor_values.append(i) 
    
    return len(factor_values)
```

If you want to find the factors of numbers without `1` and the number itself, then:

```
def factor(n):
    factor_values = []
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            factor_values.append(i) 
    
    return len(factor_values)
```

Or in another way you can just count the factors:

```
def factor(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2, n):
        if the_num % i == 0:
            count += 1 
    
    return count
```